# getting error as "Your application manifest is not properly set up for GCM"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, push

Dears,
I need to remove the push notifications from my app completely. I had commented the GCMIntentService and others in the AndroidManifest file and also commented the push calls in the javascript methods and HTML init methods.
But, still after login I am getting an error popup saying "**Failed registering for push notifications. The application will not be able to receive notifications. Your application manifest is not properly set up for GCM.........**" with an "Ok" button. Clicking the "Ok", the message disappears and application works fine.
I just need to disappear the popup.
How can I do that? From where this popup is showing?

Comment: Is this MFP 7.1?

Comment: Yes, this is MFP7.1